# Can Iranian-Canadians enter on arrival to the US?

Tags: visas, usa, canadian-citizens, iranian-citizens

I am an Iranian-Canadian dual citizen studying in the US with an F1 visa. My parents are both dual citizens as well. I understand that Canadians are not affected by the recent bill placing restrictions on the Visa Waiver Program for people who are dual citizens of, or have recently visited Iran and several other countries. I have heard, however, that a separate bill which *does* concern the visa provisions of NAFTA is in the works.

My parents often drive me over after my breaks, so I was wondering: will they be able to cross the border on arrival without having obtained visas beforehand?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be able to do so?

Comment: Do you have any reference to support the rumor that "a separate bill which concerns the visa provisions of NAFTA is in the works"?  Also, I don't think Canadians' visa-free entry to the US has anything to do with NAFTA.  US and Canadian citizens could enter Canada and the US without visas and indeed without passports for decades before NAFTA came into being.  Furthermore, Mexico participates in NAFTA, but Mexicans still need visas to get into the US.

Comment: @phoog There are visas that are covered by NAFTA - the TN non-immigrant work visas that allow certain professionals who are citizens of one of the 3 countries to temporarily work in the other with reduced red tape, but that's not what he's talking about.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Canadians can enter the US in TN status without a visa, however, thanks to the general visa exemption enjoyed by Canadians.  That of course does not apply to Mexicans.  My point is simply that NAFTA has nothing to do with the visa exemption.

Comment: @phoog Agreed. Just trying to reconcile with what the OP has 'heard'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The restrictions made by the Congress on those possessing Iranian nationality are only to the Visa Waiver Program (VWP).

Canada is not a participant in the Visa Waiver Program. Canadians entering the US on Canadian passports do not do so under the VWP.

I do not believe your parents will be affected by these changes.

http://canada.usembassy.gov/visas/information-for-canadians.html

Comment: If you (they) are not on a watch list, and show your (their) Canadian passports only, and have no Iranian stamps in those passports, then the U.S. officer has no reason to delay you (them).