# Is a citizen of Canada required to apply for a US visitor visa after visiting Iran?

Tags: usa, canadian-citizens, iran

Under new rules, non-US citizens from Visa Waiver Program countries who have visited Iraq, Syria, Iran, Sudan, Libya, Somalia, or Yemen are required to apply for a proper visa because they are no longer eligible for the VWP.

Does the above apply to citizens of Canada also? Canada is not a Visa Waiver Program country, but instead Canadian citizens can enter the US visa-free. If a Canadian citizen has visited Iran for example, is the entry procedure to the US any different?

I have looked through [Visa Waiver Program Improvement and Terrorist Travel Prevention Act Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/visa-waiver-program/visa-waiver-program-improvement-and-terrorist-travel-prevention-act-faq) but that page does not mention Canada.

Comment: Given that Canadian citizens were [not affected by the more stringent travel ban enacted by the Trump administration in January](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/canadian-affected-trump-travel-ban-refugees-immigrants-1.3957059) (and partially in force since June), I suspect the answer is no.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: I suspect so too, but I can't seem to find any evidence stating so.

Comment: related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61715/can-iranian-canadians-enter-on-arrival-to-the-us and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64917/canadian-iranian-citizen-transiting-usa-aiport

Comment: The answer is contained in the question: Canada is not a visa waiver program country.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. Canada is not part of the Visa Waiver Program; Canadian citizens enter the US without needing visas under a different provision of law. Restrictions to the Visa Waiver Program do not affect Canadian citizens. There are no conditions that will cause a Canadian citizen traveling on a Canadian passport to need a US visitor visa.

Comment: However, a border guard with a bad attitude can give you a hard time even if your passport doesn't have a stamp from Iran.

Comment: Overstaying in the US would prevent a Canadian from traveling without a special waiver in the future.

Comment: @JonathanReez: If a Canadian has a ban according to US law (and having "overstayed" does not necessarily mean they have a ban), they need to wait until the ban is over or get a waiver in order to enter the US, just like a foreigner from any other country. But regardless of whether a Canadian citizen has a ban or not, and regardless of whether they have overstayed or not, they do not need a US visitor visa.